# mod_rewrite: avoid similar URLs go to the same page.php

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to work with `mod_rewrite` without particular problems but this:

```
RewriteRule ^(product/)([^/\<\>].+?)(/)([^/\<\>].+?)(/edit)/?$             php/prd_edit.php
RewriteRule ^(product/)([^/\<\>].+?)(/)([^/\<\>].+?)(/components/edit)/?$  php/prd_comp_edit.php
```

the `first URL` is for this kind of contents when I'd like to edit the main infos:

```
http://site.com/product/Nintento/Wii/edit => php/prd_edit.php
```

the `second URL` is when I'd like to edit the list of components inside the products

```
http://site.com/product/Nintento/Wii/components/edit => php/prd_comp_edit.php
```

If I digit the `second URL`, `mod_rewrite` redirect the requesto to `prd_edit.php` instead of `prd_comp_edit.php`, because it read `Wii/components` as a product name.

I thougt to avoid this by use `([^/\<\>].+?)` to specify the product can't have chars like `/` but it still read the product name as `Wii/components`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move the second rewrite first and add [L] flags to them, this will fix your problem and here are some more optimisations.

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.+?)/(.+?)/components/edit/?$ php/prd_comp_edit.php?cat1=$1&cat2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/(.+?)/(.+?)/edit/?$ php/prd_edit.php?cat1=$1&cat2=$2 [L]
```

Now, given your example, `$_GET['cat1'] == "Nintendo"` and `$_GET['cat2'] == "wii"`

Comment: sorry but this doesn't seems to work, I still have the problem I get as product name Wii/components

Comment: Did you add the [L] tag? Otherwise it will match the first one, then match the second one and override it...

Comment: sorry, my mistake, It's been very useful see this example, I've fixed it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product
RewriteRule /components/edit/?$ php/prd_comp_edit.php [L]
RewriteRule /edit/?$ php/prd_edit.php [L]
```

This way you will be able to have deeper nested product groups as well :D

**EDIT**

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Split the URI apart using explode or any other suitable method
$parts = explode('/', rtrim($uri, '/'));

// Now throw away any part that is not connected to a product
// You know that the URI started with product and also know
// that it ended with components and/or edit

// $x = file is prd_comp_edit.php ? 3 : 2
$parts = array_slice($parts, 1, count($parts) - $x);

// Now there you have it, the products hierarchy ready to be processed further
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not a mod_rew and htaccess master, where I should insert the vars like manufacturer and product name?

Comment: You would tackle that in your application rather than within .htaccess as this can be a PITA when finer grained rules must be implemented. Look at my EDIT, it'll guide you in the right direction.